# cannot install filezilla

Tags: 14.04

when i install filezilla
appear message

```
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 avidemux2.6-gtk : Depends: avidemux2.6-common but it is not going to be installed
 avidemux2.6-jobs-qt4 : Depends: avidemux2.6-common but it is not going to be installed
 avidemux2.6-qt4 : Depends: avidemux2.6-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Well, did you run `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get build-dep filezilla && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install filezilla ` ?